# Jest promise returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My code:

```
this.apiStore.fetchOrder(id).then(() => {
  alert("Success");
  // TODO - ui updates
})
```

Jest test:

```
  describe("order", () => {
    it("fetches the order", () => {
      const fetchOrder = jest.fn();
      const id = 100;
      expect(fetchOrder).toHaveBeenCalledWith(id);
    });
  });
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Any idea on how to fix this?

Edit 1:

Fetchorder api call is defined as follows

```
fetchOrder = (orderId) => {
    return this.fetch(
      `/api/order.json`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          id: orderId
        },
      }
    );
  };
```

For now i am returning the response as

```
{"status":"ok"}
```

if i remove the `.then() => {..}` then the test is running fine. Any ideas?

Edit 2: The backend code is as follows

```
def fetch_order
  render json: { status: :ok }
end
```

Comment: Please show us the code for fetchOrder, and if you've mocked it please show us the mock.

Comment: @NicholasTower: Added the code and response data

Comment: `For now i am returning the response as {"status":"ok"}` Please show us the code that does the mocking.

Comment: @NicholasTower: Added the backend code

Comment: You misunderstand, i'm not asking about the backend code, but your test code. In order for `expect(fetchOrder).toHaveBeenCalledWith(id)` to work, you must be mocking or at least spying on fetchOrder in your test. So i'm looking for the test code that sets this up. It probably includes `jest.mock` or `jest.spyOn` or `jest.fn`.

Comment: @NicholasTower i added the full test scenario

Answer (score -1):

The fetchOrder function does not return a Promise instance, you should check its implementation or share it.